# button not visible to selenium although clearly loaded

Tags: python, html, selenium, linkedin-api

i'm trying to automate job search for 'easy apply' jobs on linkedin

for some reason i get error message " could not be scrolled into view" when im trying to click the 'Apply' button for 'easy apply' jobs
although it looks like it is visible and fully loaded

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@data-control-name='filter_pill_apply']").click()
```

HTML of element i'm trying to manipulate:

```
<button data-control-name="filter_pill_apply" id="ember2631" class="facet-collection-list__apply-button ml2 artdeco-button artdeco-button--2 artdeco-button--primary ember-view" type="button"><!---->
<span class="artdeco-button__text">
    Apply
</span>
</button>
```

also, it seems that no scrolling down will solve this issue, what can i do instead?

Comment: Could you add some of the page source HTML? This will help track down the issue.

Comment: The button you have located is not visible. Either there is more than one button that matches your locator or you have the wrong locator. You will need to post some HTML and do a little more research and update your question if you need more help.

Comment: ```
<button data-control-name="filter_pill_apply" id="ember2631" class="facet-collection-list__apply-button ml2 artdeco-button artdeco-button--2 artdeco-button--primary ember-view" type="button"><!---->
<span class="artdeco-button__text">
    Apply
</span></button>
```

this is the HTML part im trying to manipulate,
i've tried to add a picture but my ranking is not high enoufh on stackoverflow
@Christine
@JeffC

Comment: @avish The HTML is just fine, and it is better than a picture anyway, so do not worry about adding the picture. I have updated with an answer and new XPath to try. if this does not work, please provide the LinkedIn URL for page you are automating

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following path to click the small 'Easy apply' text on the right side of the page, that appears next to certain job listings.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'easy-apply')]").click();
```

You can use this next selector to click the large 'Easy Apply' button on the job description itself, which appears after you select a job from the list of jobs:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Easy Apply']//ancestor::button").click();
```

Comment: thanks @Christine, it didn't work unfortunately, i got the error: Unable to locate element: //button[span[contains(text(), 'Apply')]]

URL is: https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?f_LF=f_JIYN&keywords=software

i was able to click on the 'Easy Apply' check box, but not the apply button, maybe it is covered by aother css element?

Comment: @avish I have navigated to the page and tested out another XPath that should lead to the 'Easy Apply' button. let me know if this works at all. I had some confusion about which 'Easy apply' you wanted to click, because there are two-- the small text on left side of page, and the bigger button on right side of page.

Comment: i'm trying to apply search filter so that it will only look for 'easy apply' jobs
i think i can go around it by actually loading webdriver on the url i provided to you, in which the filter option is already on, and login from there, it might work @Christine

Comment: The filter was not applied when I clicked on the link, but I manually applied it. if loading webdriver to the URL does not apply the easy apply filter, we can use webdriver to apply it anyway. just let me know if you would like help with that.

Comment: I've used another solution to go around it, first login, and than manually loading webDriver with the URL with the selected filters already applied, i should post a more generic question - "How to make elements viewable in viewport", i want to thank you for your help, i've learned from it @Christine

Comment: You're welcome. If you are satisfied with my answer to this specific post, feel free to mark it as answered. I will keep an eye for other questions you post & see if I can help.